# Exeption: Error happened when building observer, but it was captured since desableErrorBoundarie==true

Tags: flutter, storage

i want upload an image profile with flutter, but i get error.
This is the error:"Exeption: Error happened when building observer, but it was captured since desableErrorBoundarie==true"

I'm using flutter and i want upload an image in my project.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you add your code to the question. Please see [mre] for more details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.